# Integer Math Array Optimization?

Tags: arrays, optimization

I'm looking for optimization of this function:

```
public bool isDivideEvenly (int[] num, int[] div)
{    
    for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
    {    
        for (int y = 0; y < div.length; y++)
        {    
            if (num[x] % div[y] == 0) return true;
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the contents of `num` and `div`? (I assume you want a `return false;` at the end, by the way...)

Comment: Make sure your compiler/JIT is correctly vectorizing the loop? Not much you can do without more knowledge about the data. Glow's idea could work for large arrays though.

Answer (score 1):

in a similar vein to @glowcoder's answer - it may be a win to filter the divisors of `div` first to remove multiples.  For example, no need to keep 9 if you have 3.

The effectiveness of this would be very data dependent. It would work best if `div` was much smaller than `num` and had many multiples.  It would just add cost if `div` was all primes.

Comment: no info about array contents or size...assume bad case scenarios (very large with almost zero dupes)

Answer (score 0):

If you sort `div`, you could do some searching on it that would allow you to reduce the number of divs. Whether or not this will save you time is dependent on the machine and your data. But, for example, if your smallest number is 1 and your largest number is smaller than the current `x` value, you don't need to search the array because none of them will work.